# Is there a C debugger which allows programming of break points?

Tags: c, gdb

What I am looking for is something like this -

```
Set Breakpoint 1
Set Breakpoint 2
Disable Breakpoint 2
Set dbg_counter to 0
Increment dbg_counter everytime Breakpoint 1 is reached
If dbg_counter > 100:
   Enable (once) Breakpoint 2
   Set dbg_counter to 0
```

Please note that 'dbg_counter' is a variable that only the debugger is aware of (i.e. not part of the program being debugged).

Comment: Not getting. what exactly question?

Comment: I would use gdb. I am not sure of it allows to create own variables, but you can always call `malloc` and allocate some memory for `dbg_counter`.

Comment: Not exactly for gdb, but Visual Studio has exactly this feature. Set a breakpoint, right click on it, choose Condition and write in the condition you need. Done.

Comment: @Jayesh - I want to conditionally enable/disable breakpoints based on variables defined in the debugger's environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information provided by @Thomas Padron-McCarthy about [convenience variables](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html) I was able to come up with the following GDB [command file](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html#Command-Files) to solve my problem -

```
break file.c:20
break file.c:35
disable 2
set $dbg_count = 0
commands 1
set $dbg_count += 1
if $dbg_count > 100 
enable once 2
set $dbg_count = 0
end
end
run
```

Answer (score 6):

From https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html:

> GDB provides convenience variables that you can use within GDB to hold
>   on to a value and refer to it later. These variables exist entirely
>   within GDB; they are not part of your program, and setting a
>   convenience variable has no direct effect on further execution of your
>   program.

A convenience variable can be used with a breakpoint condition to ignore a breakpoint a certain number of times. But there is an easier way to do that. From https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Conditions.html:

> A special case of a breakpoint condition is to stop only when the
>   breakpoint has been reached a certain number of times. This is so
>   useful that there is a special way to do it, using the ignore count of
>   the breakpoint. Every breakpoint has an ignore count, which is an
>   integer. Most of the time, the ignore count is zero, and therefore has
>   no effect. But if your program reaches a breakpoint whose ignore count
>   is positive, then instead of stopping, it just decrements the ignore
>   count by one and continues. As a result, if the ignore count value is
>   n, the breakpoint does not stop the next n times your program reaches
>   it.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of "convenience variables"; it helped.   

I was aware of 'ignore count' but it wasn't of use to me because I do not have apriori knowledge of the ignore count (because Break point 1 was conditional).